# API em banco de sistema existente

Tags: aplicação-web, rest, cakephp-3, orm

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida, em nossa empresa temos um sistema, desenvolvido em MySQL e Delphi, este sistema é desenvolvido por uma empresa, e estamos com vários projetos de desenvolvimento, vários novos sistemas (criados dentro da nossa empresa) são feitos com o CakePHP, estamos com planos de integrar tudo.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, vale a pena tentar desenvolver uma camada rest que faça conexão a este banco de dados MySQL usando o CakePHP para dar retornos as outras aplicações?

Seguir as convenções do CakePHP para tal valem a pena? Não seriam mais ágil desenvolver na unha ou usar algum outro framework ORM para acesso e leitura das tabelas do banco de dados existentes?

Comment: se o sistema em delphy for grande demais para a equipe refazer no php, então cria um webservice no cake que acessa os dados de lá, mas eu sempre prefiro me livrar de sistema legado e fazer um novo com boas práticas, mas ai vai da empresa. conhece [laravel](https://laravel.com)?

Comment: Sim já ouvi falar de Laravel, mas a empresa está usando CakePHP mesmo, sobre o Delphi não iremos pagar para eles desenvolver a API sairá muito caro, mas também não desenvolveremos um sistema inteiro do zero, acho que o jeito é usar CakeHPP mesmo então para fazer  o mapeamento das tabelas já existentes